# my guestbook will not display the posts i enter

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I want to thank you in advance for helping me with my related issue. The thing is my guestbook is getting the data into the database so it is connecting but when i hit submit the data goes to the database but does not display i am not sure as this maybe be a version conflict. I was watching YouTube in creating this guestbook but not sure what version the guy that created the guestbook. Everything works except the display of the post. I was wondering if you guys could help me with this and i will post code below.

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE ^ E_DEPRECATED); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Title of the document</title>
    </head>


    <body>
<?php
// connect to the database
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('tutorials');


/* * ************************************************* */
// form and add stuff area

echo "<h3> Enter posts to GuestBook </h3>";

if ($_POST['postbtn']) {

    $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
    $email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);

    if ($name && $email && $message) {


        $time = date("h:i A");
        $date = date("F d, Y");
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        // add to the database
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO guestbook VALUES ( '', '$name', '$email', '$message', '$time', '$date', 'ip'
            )");

        echo "Your post has been added.";
    } else {

        echo "You did not enter in all the required information";
    }
}
echo "<form action = './guestbook.php' method = 'post'>

    <table>


        <tr>

            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input type = 'text' name = 'name' style = 'width: 300px;' /></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><input type = 'text' name = 'email' style = 'width: 300px;' /></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Message:</td>
            <td><textarea  name = 'message' style = 'width: 300px; height: 300px;'></textarea></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td></td>
            <td><input type = 'submit' name = 'postbtn' value = 'Post' /></td>

        </tr>


    </table>




    </form>";

/* * ************************************************ */
//display stuff area

echo "<h3> Current Posts </h3>";
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guestbook ORDER BY id DESC");

$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if ($numrows > 0) {
    echo "<hr />"; //echoing out the top horizontal line    
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {

        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $message = $row['message'];
        $time = $row['time'];
        $date = $row['date'];
        $ip = $row['ip'];


        //nl2br new line to break function
        $message = nl2br("message");

        echo "<div>

            By <b>$name</b> - at <b>$time</b> on <b>$date </b><br />
            $message
        </div> <hr />";
    }
} else {

    echo "No posts were found.";
}

mysql_close();
?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the textarea box and sql query work, just do not know why it is not displaying.

Comment: here is my pastebin where all the code is displayed. http://pastebin.com/TpG0L8hy

Comment: I could not get it to format right here

Comment: i am running php 5.6.3, mysql of 5.6, and xampp of 5.63

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pluralized `rows` in your `while` loop:

```
while ( $rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query) ){
            ^ - plural

    $id = $row['id'];
              ^ no "s" - singular
```

`while ( $rows` where you're using `$row` for everything else, which is why it's not displaying any of your rows.

Use `while ( $row` in singular form.

---

I need to point out that your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Comment: thank you it is supposed to be rows to i changed row to rows. Now it is getting the name date and time but not displaying message

Comment: @jc `$message = nl2br("message");` you're using "message" instead of using the row for it. Do `$message = nl2br($row['message']);` and get rid of `$message = nl2br("message");`

Comment: the date is also off too its kind of weird

Comment: @jc If you want to concatenate the word "message" before each row, then do `$message = "message: " . nl2br($row['message']);`

Comment: @jc I believe I answered the initial question. You can mark this as solved. Post a new question if needed.

Comment: your awesome that fixed my message